# corrplot.mixed in R - make labels in the diagonal smaller

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, correlation

I used this command to get a correlation matrix plot. Everything works fine, but the diagonal. The labels are slightly longer and they do not fit. How can this be fixed? - either making the labels smaller or changing the direction of the letter.  I have tried a couple of things, but none of them seems to work.

```
cor.matrix <- round(cor(grades, use = "pairwise.complete.obs", method = "kendall"), digits = 2)
corrplot.mixed(cor.matrix,  tl.col = "black", lower.col = "black",number.cex = .7,tl.cex=1 )
```

[image]

Comment: it is just above the plot

Comment: you should use `dput(cor.matrix)` and add that to the question, to make this reproducible.

Answer (score 4):

I actually just found a way to solve this. Instead of trying to do this within the plot i have renamed the labels of my data. By using `\n` for line break I manage to split the name and thus make it shorter. Also the label size can be adjusted via `cex=0.8` within `corrplot.mixed`

```
colnames(grades) <- c("Theory", "Building \n Science", "Buliding\n Technique", "Design 1", "Design 2", "Design 3", "Testscore")

corrplot.mixed(cor.matrix,  tl.col = "black", lower.col = "black",number.cex = .7,tl.cex=0.8 )
```

[image]